# GoogleAppEngine JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-app-engine

I want to create a dictionary containing array and send it to GAE using jquery's ajax request.
something like- `{'a':'text', 'b':'othertext','c':['texta','textb']}` which I'm creating manually.
I am able to receive and process a and b using self.request.get on GAE but not the c.

Is there any other way to create JSON object in js? Please suggest whats wrong in this method.

Comment: What jQuery code are you using to send the request? I don't know much about Python GAE but it seems that request.get deals with normal GET and POST parameters, not JSON properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, GAE's `self.request.get` is not able to serialize a complex object like a string array into a GET request format (`?a=text&b=othertext...`).

One workaround, although perhaps not a very neat one, would be to serialize the value to JSON yourself, and pass that:

```
var jsonObj = {
               'a':'text', 
               'b':'othertext', 
               'cJSON': JSON.stringify(['texta', 'textb'])
              };
```

... and then of course you'd have to deserialize `cJSON` at the receiving end.

Answer (score 4):

You're not really sending JSON to the server. When you pass the object to `jQuery.ajax` (or the `get`/`post` wrappers), it will be serialized into GET or POST variables, not sent as JSON, so your object would be converted into something like this:

```
a=text&b=othertext&c[]=texta&c[]=textb
```

If you want to pass the entire object as JSON, you can convert it yourself by calling `JSON.stringify` (you will need to include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) for browsers that don't support the `JSON` object natively). Then you can wrap the JSON-encoded string in a map with whatever name you want:

```
jQuery.post(url, { json: JSON.stringify({a:'text', ...}) }, ...);
```

On the server side, you can access the JSON text by calling `self.request.get("json")`. Then you would have to parse the JSON string to extract the values. I don't know much about Python, but apparently you just need to import `django.utils.simplejson` and call `simplejson.loads(json)`.

Comment: I understood what you meant but Davids solution worked for me, +1 for your detailed ans. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually sending urlencoded request parameters, not JSON. JQuery is probably encoding the list as multiple values for the same parameter, which means you can access it using `self.request.get_all`, which will return a list - `self.request.get` will only return the first value.

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried get_all, but It was not working when I was sending 'c':['texta','textb']

Comment: @Cool: Not that this matters since you got it working already, but `get_all` would probably work if you call it like this: `self.request.get_all("c[]")`. By default, jQuery uses PHP's convention of puting '[]' at the end to treat the parameter as an array.